# Вывод имен файлов через командную строку(windows)

Tags: командная-строка

Вывести список всех файлов указанного каталога, имена которых состоят только из русских букв. Всем спасибо!

Comment: win? linux? mac?

Comment: Винда, забыл указать

Comment: Именно с русскими символами там всё плохо...

Comment: А если с английскими? Мне просто пример нужен, как это работает)

Comment: `dir /b | findstr /i "^[a-z]*$"`

Answer (score 0):

На линуксах `sudo find | grep '^\./[а-яА-Я]`.

На Windows с латиницей так: `dir /b | findstr /i "^[a-z]*$"`. С кириллицей там проблемы...